# Is there a way to iterate through a range in using the excel javascript api?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Is there a way to iterate through a range in using the excel javascript api? I have two columns and rows of data. In each row if one column has data in it the other should not. The other column should be 0 or null. I would like to highlight rows where both the columns have data. I have added an image of what I want to achieve.

[image: An image of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clean this up as need be, you should be able to do what you need to do.

```
const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();    

let dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:B10").load(["rowCount", "values"]);
await context.sync();

for (var row = 0; row < dataRange.rowCount; row++) {
  let column1 = dataRange.values[row][0];
  let column2 = dataRange.values[row][1];

  dataRange.getRow(row).format.fill.clear();

  if (column1 !== "" && column2 !== "")
    dataRange.getRow(row).format.fill.color = "Red";
}

await context.sync();
```

Comment: You should load the rowCount property explicitly rather than just calling the load method. Calling load without a parameter is not recommended since it can lead to poor performance. You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/application-specific-api-model#calling-load-without-parameters-not-recommended

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Thank you.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez, I changed it just for you.  :-)

Comment: ``` 
return context.sync().then(function () {...}
```
I have seen examples where instead of using await on context.sync() to load the functions, some use then. I've been reading on javascript, and found out using then is not the modern approach to handle asynchronous code. is my understanding correct?

Comment: @jalwan You are correct. Async/await is a more modern approach, which leads to much simpler code.  However, I still find regular promise notation (.then()) to be useful when I have many independent tasks to accomplish simultaneously.